# Spring Boot -- Post request with CSRF token produce 403 error

Tags: java, spring-boot, csrf, csrf-token

I'm trying to implement CSRF token security in my Spring Boot API to learn how to deal with that.

I've followed [this tutorial (server side part)](http://roufid.com/angular-spring-security-csrf-configuration/#server_side_configuration) and this is my security config:

```
private static final String[] CSRF_IGNORE = {"/api/login"};


protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .ignoringAntMatchers(CSRF_IGNORE)
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(new CustomCsrfFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint() {
                })
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(getProvider())
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/api/login")
                .successHandler(new AuthentificationLoginSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new AuthentificationLogoutSuccessHandler())
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

Others things are the same as in the tutorial.

I'm testing with Postman.

When i add the endpoint i want in **CSRF_IGNORE**, i can see with logger/debug that token stocked, and token from cookie are the same, because the security config's part **CustomCsrfFilter.java** in **.addFilterAfter()** is used, but when i remove the endpoint from this CSRF_IGNORE, what i get is a 403, and, logger/debug in the **CustomCsrfFilter.java** isn't used, so i'm thinking that tokens aren't compared.

I think I missed something and I would like to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use CSRF with a http only false cookie, why not use Spring Security's built in `CookieCsrfTokenRepository`? Should simplify your config that way. `CustomCsrfFilter` seems to be adding a `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie to the `HttpServletResponse`, which `CookieCsrfTokenRepository` [does for you](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/csrf/CookieCsrfTokenRepository.java#L66).

The default CSRF cookie name when using `CookieCsrfTokenRepository` is `X-CSRF-TOKEN`, which is conveniently the default name Angular's `HttpClientXsrfModule` uses. Of course you can customize that if you need.

So your security config becomes:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())
                .and()
                    .authenticationProvider(getProvider())
                .formLogin()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/api/login")
                    .successHandler(new AuthentificationLoginSuccessHandler())
                    .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(new AuthentificationLogoutSuccessHandler())
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

And with Angular, your app module has `HttpClientXsrfModule` as

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientXsrfModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.

Before to ask help, i tried with  the built in `CookieCsrfTokenRepository`, but it was the same.

Now, to do it the right way,  I tried to do like you said, and it's more simple than adding a csrf token repository. I also deleted my custom csrf filter from the security config.

Now, i'm on the same problem. Post request on endpoints who are not in the `.ignoringAntMatchers` gives me a 403 error.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Nevermind, it's working now, i just had to add in headers (in postman) the X-XSRF-TOKEN.

Now, if i have understand, i need send in my front, in headers, the token wich is in the cookie.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas this helped me a lot, adding that header in postman request :)

Comment: @drumonii, This is unrelated to your answer, but do you happen to remember how to get your security config format like that? you doing it manually or do you have a formatting config you use to set that? I've never been able to find it.

Comment: @BrentThoenen, I formatted it manually. You may want to use `// @formatter:off` and `// @formatter:on` so that your IDE ignores those config lines when you format the entire security config class.

Comment: @drumonii, I have tried implementing the csrftokenrepository along with sending the header X-XSRF-TOKEN in the request header while sending the POST request in POSTMAN but I am still getting 403 Forbidden error. Please find below the code snippet in my configuration file:

http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and().authorizeHttpRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/secure/register").permitAll();

Comment: @Iqbal it's hard to tell without seeing your full code and your request. might suggest posting your own question and linking here

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is kind of old, I've been struggling with the same issue for the last couple of days. A lot of people suggest to add:

```html
       <th:input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                        value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

into your form. Despite of that, the csrf-token isn't send.
For me the problem was solved by moving the html-file, containing the form into the template folder of my Spring Boot project. It seems as if thymeleaf is only then able to add the csrf-token automatically.